# How can I have sub-radio buttons in angular depending on the radio buttons?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to have *radio buttons* and *sub radio buttons*.

If I click on the **first radio**, the sub radios for this button will be shown. If I click the **second radio**, the sub-radio of the second button will be shown, etc.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let answer of blabla">
    <ion-item text-wrap class="sub-item">
      <ion-label>{{answer.label}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="{{answer.value}}" (ionSelect)="select(question, answer)"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-list radio-group>
      <ng-container *ngIf="XXXXXXX">
        <ion-item text-wrap class="sub-sub-item" *ngFor="let subAnswer of answer.getSubAnswers()">
          <ion-label>{{subSubAnswer.label}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio (ionSelect)="changeAnswer(question, answer)"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ng-container>
    </ion-list>
</ng-container>
```

Which test can I done in `ngIf="XXXXXXX"` to detect if the **first radio** button is checked or not?

Or have you maybe another solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think you could manage with some `typeScript`

in your component set a variable, let say named `selectedFirstAnswer` with default falue null, then you could work with this:

`select(question, answer) {
    // ...your code
    this.selectedFirstAnswer = answer`

then in your `*ngIf` you can test this value.

I hope i helped you with this kind of trick.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, but in my case I have dynamic radio inputs. Than I don't know how many buttons I will have and which will be first, second, etc

Comment: if i understand you, this cycle could last for more than 2 radio button set?

anyway, i think you can adapt this kind of solution for whatever case you'll have